# How to update a long list of documents (rows) in mongodb based on the expiring date?

Tags: mongodb

I would need a cron job that filters all the rows that have (travellingPath.endDate>now) and set them (travellingPath.isActive=false). The travelling path has a toCity property. Now I want to update the quantity of the toCity based on the quantity of the travellingPath and another settings collection.

For example:

- a travelling path expired
- cron job catches it
- get the toCity from the travelling path
- get the conversionRate from another collection
- based on the **toCity.quantity**, **travellingPath.quantity**, **conversionRate** and **random** I update the toCity.quantity to a new value, and I also might change the toCity.owner
- update the travelling path to isActive=false

My idea would be to query each travelling path that has endDate>now but this could end up with 100000 results so it's not great. I might limit it to 250 results to work properly. Then for each travellingPath I get it's toCity and make the calculations and update the toCity and the travellingPath.

But this seems so not efficient..

do you have better ideas? thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to go. MongoDB updates don't support expressions that depend on other fields. So you're stuck with this:

1. Retrieve documents one by one or in small batches;
2. Calculate new values for the fields;
3. Send updates to the database (one by one or in batches);
4. Get next portion of documents, repeat until done.

Comment: there would be some big delays, right? one would expect to a travellingpath to be in the new city at 14:57:30 but will only be updated at 14:58:40 for example. The delay was 70seconds, and this would not be so acceptable.. I would have to make a KPI of how many seconds of delays per travellingpath are in order to control it?

Comment: and what about the chron-job, must be run every 3 min? or what interval is best?

Comment: Well, this totally depends on your app. Can't you do the updates at the same time when you update `travellingPath`?

Comment: i update the travelling path at the same time with the city. but anyway there will be an error between the expectedEndDate and the realEndDate, but this are not a problem, now are the random game variables. A perfect match would allow my client to update the ui on the endDate, now will wait more (the random delay) and will wait for a server confirmation. thanks anyway.